# DRF method GET not allowed on @action based function

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the two models: Article and Comment. I have the ArticleAPI viewset, which have methods decorated with @action to handle requests to comments model, but when I am trying to test this endpoint via Postman I get an error:

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
}
```

ArticleAPI.py

```
class ArticleAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly
    ]
    queryset = Article.objects.order_by('number')
    lookup_field = 'pk'

    ...

    @action(methods=['GET'], detail=True,
            url_path='comments', url_name='article-comments-list')
    def get_comments_queryset(self, request):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = CommentSerializer(queryset=instance.comment_set.all(), many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @action(methods=['GET'], detail=True,
            url_path='comments', url_name='article-comments-object')
    def get_comment_object(self, request, pk=None):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = CommentSerializer(queryset=instance.comment_set.get(pk=pk))
        return Response(serializer.data)
    @action(methods=['post'], detail=True,
            url_path='comments', url_name='article-create-comment')
    def create_comment(self, request):
        serializer = CommentSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.create(serializer.data)
        return Response({
            "comment": serializer.data
        }, status=201)

    @action(methods=['patch'], detail=True,
            url_path='comments', url_name='article-update-comment')
    def partial_update_comment(self, request):
        instance = self.get_object()

        if not self.check_self_or_admin(request, instance):
            return Response({
                "errors": "Logged in user and author must be same"
            }, status=403)

        serializer = CommentSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.partial_update(serializer.data)
        return Response({
            "comment": serializer.data
        })

    @action(methods=['delete'], detail=True,
            url_path='comments', url_name='article-update-comment')
    def delete_comment(self, request):
        instance = self.get_object()

        if not self.check_self_or_admin(request, instance):
            return Response({
                "errors": "Logged in user and author must be same"
            }, status=403)

        self.perform_destroy(instance)
        return Response(status=204)
```

urls.py

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('articles', articleAPI.ArticleAPI, basename='articles')
```

**UPD:**
my routes related to comments

```
<URLPattern '^articles/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/comments/$' [name='articles-article-create-comment']>, <URLPattern '^articles/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/comments/$' [na
me='articles-article-update-comment']>, <URLPattern '^articles/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/comments/$' [name='articles-article-comments-object']>, <URLPattern '^articles/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/comments/$' [name='articles-article-comments-list']>, <URLPattern '^articles/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/co
mments/$' [name='articles-article-update-comment']>]
```

**UPD 2:**
Also POST and other method are not working

Comment: What if you use `methods=['get']`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem nothing changed

Comment: You have two routes with the same `url_name`, does that have something to do with it?  We have many and have no issues, maybe you can print out all your urls, and indicate which specific one you are calling that is raising the issue?  Also, just use `SimpleRouter` unless you need the default document in the root - its a poorly named class, most people just want the Simple one.

Comment: @Andrew Ok, see upd